# C# Login form with two types of account

Tags: c#, authentication, types, account

I have to types of accounts: Administrator and Student. I want Administrator to be able to open RecordStudent Form and other forms, while the Student type can only open the Subject form.

Login Form:

```
namespace WindowsTest
{
    public partial class LogIn : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=dbEnroll;Integrated Security=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        SqlDataReader dr;
        public LogIn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLogIn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            string sql = "select*from tblAccount where Type='Administrator' or Type='Student' and Username like '%" + txtUsername.Text + "%' and Password like '%" + txtPassword.Text + "%'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            dr.Read();
            try
            {
                if (dr.HasRows == true)
                {
                    txtUsername.Text = dr[1].ToString();
                    txtPassword.Text = dr[2].ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show("Successfully Login", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
                    Enrollment enroll = new Enrollment(); 
                    enroll.Show();
                    this.Hide();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Username or Password", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            dr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It looks like you posted code for the login form, but not the code that decides if the user can open a specific form. Could you please show the code and describe exactly what isn't working?

Comment: While editing code please make sure to use SQL parametrized queries instead of string concatenation to avoid food of "SQL injection" comments.

Comment: Just don't. I could take your app and wipe your database in a flash... There are many issues with your current code. Desktop code lends itself very easily to being decompiled, so your security measures amount to security-by-obscurity, offering no real defense. You need to add a middle-tier to your architecture (a web server) and to have your application fetch data from the web server. Now you can use the existing membership/authentication frameworks available in ASP.NET and keep access to the database away from the client.

Comment: ...you also appear to be storing passwords in plain-text... so now I can also grab all your usernames and passwords. Don't try to roll your own authentication. It's devilishly difficult to get right. You've probably got things that haven't already been solved by someone else to concentrate on .